# Nested If Statement

Tags: java, if-statement, nested

I have a code written below which is pretty much one if statement nested into another, therefore when running the code below if the first if statement is incorrect the nested if statement won't run either.

I know this means that you aren't able to make the 2nd if statement true but my question is simple:

Is the 2nd if statement true but ignored due to the 1st if statement being false or is the 2nd if statement false altogether?

The code for my question is below:

```
int temperature;
myWindow.clearOut();
temperature = Integer.parseInt(myWindow.readIn());
if (temperature >= 18) {
    myWindow.writeOutLine(temperature + " is greater than or equal to 18");
    if (temperature % 2 == 0)
        myWindow.writeOutLine(temperature + " is an even number");

}
```

Comment: The second `if` statement is Schrödinger's cat - it's neither true nor false, since it's never evaluated.

Comment: @OriLentz Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the nested if statement is neither true or false as it is never evaluated and ignored completely. (Thanks to Ori and Berger).

Answer (score 2):

You don't know whether the 2nd if-statement would evaluate to *true* or *false* because it gets not executed if the 1st if-statement evaluates to *false*.

That is how modern programming languages work - the code that should be executed is added to a stack of commands. If the 1st statement evaluates to *false*, nothing within the if's body is added to the stack.

Answer (score 0):

There are three alternative ways to do this - you must decide for yourself.

```
/**
 * Warning on temp >= 18.
 * Warning on temp >= 18 && temp is even.
 */
public void test1() {
    if (temperature >= 18) {
        myWindow.writeOutLine(temperature + " is greater than or equal     to 18");
        if (temperature % 2 == 0) {
            myWindow.writeOutLine(temperature + " is an even number");
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Warning on temp >= 18.
 * Warning on temp is even.
 */
public void test2() {
    if (temperature >= 18) {
        myWindow.writeOutLine(temperature + " is greater than or equal     to 18");
    }
    if (temperature % 2 == 0) {
        myWindow.writeOutLine(temperature + " is an even number");
    }

}

/**
 * Warning on temp >= 18.
 * Warning on temp < 18 && temp is even.
 */
public void test3() {
    if (temperature >= 18) {
        myWindow.writeOutLine(temperature + " is greater than or equal     to 18");
    } else if (temperature % 2 == 0) {
        myWindow.writeOutLine(temperature + " is an even number");
    }
}
```

Comment: I am just running a program where there are two if trap statements together as a test, correct me if I'm wrong but test3 gives the opportunity for the else if statement to be correct even if the first if statement is wrong

Comment: @TimothyKardaras - Correct, but not *opportunity*. It is `test1 -> A && B`, `test2 -> A || B || both`, `test3 -> A || B`.

Answer (score 0):

The **second** if condition is actually conditioned to the first one, because you will never know if the temperature is even until it is true that it is greater than 18...

such a *cascade conditions* can be a pit fall to find bugs in the application...

I will suggest to reorder the conditions

Comment: I understand the indentation may be a little sloppy but what is wrong with the order of my conditions, especially with such a small program?

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd if statement `if (temperature % 2 == 0)` may or may not be true, but is executed only when the 1st if statement `if (temperature >= 18)` is true.